# Filter data from database on datetimepicker input uisng MySQL, PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to do search base on the input in two datetimepicker and display the results into table, but when I pick specific date rage all data are displaying. I'm  using MySQL and PDO.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date1']));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date2']));

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_search;charset=utf8mb4', 
'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$sql = "select * from book";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($row_count > 0){
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ISBN']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['author']?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['date_published']))?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}else{
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "4"><center>Record Not Found</center></td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions (IMHO) and for me is a sign of getting your solution and taking off. Your communications skills need to be worked. on. Given [a comment I placed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081587/dynamic-menu-from-mysql-database#comment91113678_52081587) under [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52081587/1415724) of yours.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually included the date conditions in your query, which is why it is still returning all the data. Change your query to

```
$sql = "select * from book where date_published between '" . min($date1, $date2) . "' and '" . max($date1, $date2) . "'";
```

If you know that `$date1` is less than `$date2`, you can simplify that to

```
$sql = "select * from book where date_published between '$date1' and '$date2'";
```

Note that your code is wide open to SQL Injection, you should really use prepared statements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more info...

Comment: You didn't use the code I posted; your query `$sql = "select * from book where date_published";` is missing the rest of the `where` clause.

Comment: Hi Nick, I've tried your codes and I miss to put double quotes that's why it is not working but now it's working fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @KenjiroAikawa sorry about forgetting the quotes. I hope that didn't waste too much of your time. I've updated the answer so that if anyone else sees it they will get the right answer.

Comment: It's ok, actually because of your help I've didn't waste too much time figuring out the problem, 'till next time Nick. Thank you again.